# Getting the size of an UIView to programmatically add subviews (with calculated X, Y, width and height)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, ios-autolayout

In a segue I have an `UIVIew` which have constraints that lays it out to the same size as the screen on the top, left and right as well as to a button on the bottom:
[image]

Then from the `ViewController` I programmatically add `UIButtons` like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        drawCards()
    }


private func drawCards(){
        let deck = Deck()

        var rowIndex = 0
        var columnIndex = 0

        let cardWidth = Int(Float((deckView.bounds.width) / 7))
        let cardHeight = Int(Float(cardWidth) * 1.5)

        for card in deck.cards{
            let x = (cardWidth / 2) * columnIndex
            let y = cardHeight * rowIndex

            let button = CardButton()
            button.delegate = self
            button.setCard(card: card, x: x, y: y, width: cardWidth, height: cardHeight)

            deckView.addSubview(button)

            columnIndex += 1

            if(columnIndex == 13){
                columnIndex = 0
                rowIndex += 1
            }
        }
    }
```

The expected behavior is that this function should take the size of the `UIView` (called `deckView`), insert the `UIButtons` and to be stacked over each other and have the same layout consistently between devices. However, it looks as expected on iPhone but not on iPad as the `UIButtons` go outside of the `UIView`:
[image]

This is, as for as I can tell, because the `X` and `Y` values aren't calculated correctly because the width of the `UIView` (`deckView`) isn't retrieved correctly (or as expected).

**Why isn't the width of the `UIView` being retrieved as expected?** (i.e. why does it works as expected on iPhone but not on iPad)

Comment: do your size calculations in "viewDidAppear" method to solve this issue

Comment: Or give your view constraints programmatically w.r.t. UIScreen.main.bounds

Comment: When using viewDidAppear it seems to take calculate correctly based on the width of the UIView. However, is that the only way as it creates a lag between the segue being loaded and for the UIButtons to be added

Comment: You are right about the lag but If you are using autolayout, the view gets its size in viewdidappear, in other methods like viewdidload it will give you the size of your nib that you have used for designing.

Comment: you can hide the view or show some animation till the view gets loaded after viewDidAppear and then show this card views.

Comment: @MohitKumar I think the best place to update the layout is in `viewDidLayoutSuviews()` not `viewDidAppear`

Comment: Yes, You can write your code in viewDidLayoutSuviews() as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your `drawCards()` from `viewDidLoad` to `viewDidLayoutSuviews`

Comment: That seems to work! Note: There is a typo in the name viewDidLayoutSubviews